# Django administration added value auto delete

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I have a model name SampleType and i register this model to admin area in admin.py:
admin.site.register(SampleType)
this model code is:

```
class SampleType(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

When i login to Django administration i see this model And when i use the feature Add sample types and enter a name, it show this message:
"The sample type “SampleType object (2)” was added successfully."

but i see nothing in SampleType table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8PJQ.jpg)

and when i go to home page it shows recent actions but when i click to one of my actions this will be appear:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56F7Z.jpg)

I have no idea what is happening here. I tried to delete database and migrations and do this again but has no affect of my problem. I check the query of this model too but it is empty.

I want to add a value to my table from admin area of Django but i can't

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was using router for my application.
But when you use cursor in your application there is no need to use router. But i did this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).